# Data streaming to Google Cloud ML Engine

Tags: google-api-client, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-ml-engine

I found that Google ml engine expects data in cloud storage, big query etc. Is there any way to stream data to ml-engine. For example, imagine that I need to use data in WordPress or Drupal site to create a tensorflow model, say a spam detector. One way is to export the whole data as CSV and upload it to cloud storage using google-cloud--php library. The problem here is that, for every minor change, we have to upload the whole data. Is there any better way?

Answer (score 0):

By minor change, do you mean "when you get new data, you have to upload everything--the old and new data--again to gcs"? One idea is to export just the new data to gcs on some schedule, making many csv files over time. You can write your trainer to take a file pattern and expand it using [get_matching_files/Glob](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/platform/gfile.py) or multiple file paths.

You can also modify your training code to start from an old checkpoint and train over just the new data (which is in its own file) for a few steps.

Comment: I want to use data in my CMS (content management sysyem) independent of the trainer. I want to make my PHP CMS code public so that it can be used with any trainer.

Comment: You have to export to csv and put it on gcs. No other way.